# How do I create a JavaScript object-based representation of a directory tree

Tags: javascript, object, directory, treeview

Given a directory structure like this:

```
photos
 ├── summer
 │   └── june
 │       └── windsurf.jpg
 └── winter
     └── january
         ├── ski.png
         └── snowboard.jpg
```

should return something like this:

```
{
  "path": "photos",
  "name": "photos",
  "size": 600,
  "type": "directory",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "photos/summer",
      "name": "summer",
      "size": 400,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/summer/june",
          "name": "june",
          "size": 400,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg",
              "name": "windsurf.jpg",
              "size": 400,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "photos/winter",
      "name": "winter",
      "size": 200,
      "type": "directory",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "photos/winter/january",
          "name": "january",
          "size": 200,
          "type": "directory",
          "children": [
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/ski.png",
              "name": "ski.png",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".png"
            },
            {
              "path": "photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg",
              "name": "snowboard.jpg",
              "size": 100,
              "type": "file",
              "extension": ".jpg"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Comment: I don't even know what it is and where to start?

Comment: How are you storing the directory tree?

Comment: with javascript I guess... I honestly do not know what you are talking about and I have been searching on this  directory tree structure

Comment: I mean, what is your exact input format for javascript to make it json?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree

Comment: the information on INPUT FORMAT  I get is photos
 ├── summer
 │   └── june
 │       └── windsurf.jpg
 └── winter
     └── january
         ├── ski.png
         └── snowboard.jpg

Comment: When you say - how can you create? Do you mean you have an array of images, and you want to  know how to dynamically generate that json object above from the array?

Comment: I guess my input will be like this:

Comment: photos/summer/june/windsurf.jpg
photos/winter/january/ski.png
photos/winter/january/snowboard.jpg                                     given three directory path